# Can we prove this using Archimedean Property.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question**: let $s\in(0,1)$ then, is the following statement is true?
>
> For every $m\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
> $s<m/n$
>
> How can use Archimedean property to prove above?

I know by Archimedean property, for any two positive real numbers $m, s$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, $ns>m$ (i.e. $s>m/n$). But inequality, in above statement is reversed.

Comment: You could take $n=m$ (or $n=1$).

Comment: @DavidMitra sir, :-) i didn't think about this. Thank you.

Comment: Your question would become non trivial if you specify $ \frac mn \in (0,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use the Archimedean property to prove what you want, indeed

$s<1\leqslant\dfrac mn\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\;$ such that $\;n\leqslant m\;.$